# RTX kernel porting

Tags: eclipse, porting, keil, rtx

We have a project in `KEIL IDE` for `LPC2148` which has `RTX` kernel programs along with other programs in it.Now we need to change the IDE from `KEIL` to `Eclipse`. When we tried to compile it in Eclipse GCC Compiler it is showing errors in `RTX_Config.c` and `RTX_Config.h` files.Is there any solution to compile this project in Eclipse IDE?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: duplicate of [Compiling RTX Kernel files using GCC Compiler in Eclipse IDE][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231221/compiling-rtx-kernel-files-using-gcc-compiler-in-eclipse-ide?rq=1